# Flask does not deposit cookie correctly

Tags: python, mongodb, vue.js, flask

I have a page made in VueJS that triggers a request through axios:

```
const apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'

axios
          .post(
            `${apiUrl}/api/account/login`,
            {
              email: this.email,
              password: this.password,
            },
            {
              withCredentials: true,
            }
          )
          .then((response) => {
            alert(response.data.message);
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            alert(`${error.response.data.erro}`);
            console.log(error);
          });
```

And in the back end we have my:

```
main.py

from flask import Flask, make_response
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from user import loginAccount

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)

@app.route('/')
def principal(): return 'Welcome to the CharTwo API.'

@app.route('/api/account/login', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
def login_account(): return loginAccount()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
user.py

def loginAccount():

    userId = str(list(db['users'].find({"email": email}))[0]['_id'])

    tokenId = jwt.encode({'userId': userId}, SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')

    mensagem = {'message': f'Welcome to the CharTwo {email}!', 'tokenId': tokenId}

    response = make_response(jsonify(mensagem))

    response.set_cookie('accessToken', tokenId)

    return jsonify(mensagem)
```

The problem here is that when I inspect the cookies they don't exist.

I believe the problem is in the Python code because the same in Node worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `loginAccount()` function and what is returning. You create a variable called response, you set a message, you add `set_cookie()` but you never return that reponse, instead you just return the message. Just change it to return the `response`.

```py
def loginAccount():
    userId = str(list(db['users'].find({"email": email}))[0]['_id'])
    tokenId = jwt.encode({'userId': userId}, SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')
    mensagem = {'message': f'Welcome to the CharTwo {email}!', 'tokenId': tokenId}
    response = make_response(jsonify(mensagem))
    response.set_cookie('accessToken', tokenId)
    return response
```